# Coverage of $3D$ Points by Polyhedron

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces, soft-question, 3d, convex-geometry

A $2D$ polygon of *n* edges and vertices is projected onto the XY plane. The vertices and edges are connected forming a watertight convex polyhedron (truncated prism-ish? except angled top face) with $N + 2$ faces, lets call this polyhedron *$P$*.

I also have *m* number of 3D points in *$x,y,z$*. It is given that these points all fall within the volume of *$P$*, this is checked by getting the signed cross product from the point to each plane.

The $2D$ polygon and its projection now transform (translate, reflect or rotate but retain shape) and form a new Polyhedron (*$P'$*) with the same guarantee that *$m$* points (same coordinates) all fall within the new volume as well.

I am trying to find a way to determine which polygon covers the points better. My question is, what is a good way to define "cover better". If I were to try and define it I'd say "having the shortest single distance from each point to a plane being as equal as possible and maximized"?

I have also thought about the following ways to define/calculate "cover better":

1. Compare the average, median and standard deviation for individual and summed distance values from each point *m* to each face that makes P and P'.
2. Have the distance from a point to each plane be as equal as possible.
3. Create a line *$L$* from the centroid of the $2D$ polygon and its projection and compare the average, median and standard deviation for individual and summed distance values from each point *$m$* to each *$L$* that makes $P$ and $P'$.

Conceptual question to see what some people might think is a better way to define "covers" the points better.

Illustrations below to hopefully make things clearer with *$n$*$=4$ and *$m$*$=2$:

[image: Illustrations below to hopefully make things clearer with n=4 and m=2:]

Comment: You should explain what you mean precisely by **"shifting"** which has no precise meaning in geometry (I would say that many people would assimilate "shifting" = "translation" which is not what you mean ?)

Comment: Yes it actually is what I mean, more precisely the 2D polygon transforms (translation, reflection or rotation, shape unchanged), I have updated the original post to show transform.

Comment: 1) Why do you say in your last comment **2D** poly**gon** transforms ? In fact is your (3D) poly**hedron** rigid (if not rigid, constituted by articulated edges/hinges whose relative angles may fluctuate, the upper and lower faces keeping the same form ?) What about preservation of the lengths of the "vertical" bars ? 2) If the polyhedron was kept rigid, the expression fitting your definition (translations + rotations) would be "**rigid transform**", but strictly speaking, symetries aren't included...

Comment: The 2D polygon either translates, reflects or rotates to a new position in 3D space with the projection following suit, thus creating a new polyhedron. In hindsight I could have left out the 2D polygon business to keep the description clearer. Ultimately its 2 polyhedrons encapsulating/covering the exact same set of points within its volume, per the OP I want to discuss what are some methods in evaluating which polyhedron covers the points better (more of a discussion than a proof...probably).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but still not fully clear : when you say "the projection" (of the polygonal top face) : Is it an **orthogonal** projection (doesn't look so on your figures : if it is a slant/oblique projection,  how is given the angle of projection ? Is it any angle ? Sorry for these questions, but I must not be the single puzzled person : indeed I see no other comments...

Comment: As per the original post, the projection is onto the XY plane. Its an oblique projection. with the angle of projection being arbitrary.

Comment: Thanks. Clear now. A first answer : you will, sooner or later, have to deal with the **convex hull** of the "cloud" of points and its "shadows" in the different direction projections

Comment: Said otherwise, your issue boils down to the obtention of two different angles of projection such that the projection of your 2D polygon "best" fits/encloses the projection of the convex hull (which is a polyhedron) of the points.